# Save return response from api call to a PDF in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, pdf

I am making via RingCentral Api and I am getting the below response via a node request.  I am trying to figure out how I can save the response (which should be PDF source) so that I can then open it.

This is the response.

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/1234/message-store/1234/content/1234?contentDisposition=Inline',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

This is the code:

```
    let getMessageContent = await platform.get('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/'+accountId+'/message-store/'+attachId+'/content/'+attachId, {
        contentDisposition: ['Inline']
    })
    let jsonMessageContent = await getMessageContent.headers
        console.log(jsonMessageContent)
```

If I run the URL in post man, I can see the PDF displayed in this way.

In Postman (this is just an example)

```
%PDF-1.3
%����
1 0 obj 
<<
/Pages 2 0 R
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj 
2 0 obj 
<<
/Kids [3 0 R]
/Count 1
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj 
3 0 obj 
<<
/CropBox [0 0 609.882 818.449]
/Parent 2 0 R
/Thumb 4 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 609.882 818.449]
/Resources 
<<
/XObject
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When in the past I have needed to create an endpoint that took certain information (some of it from the very same request), produced a PDF file with it, and served it as its response I found [PDFkit](https://pdfkit.org/) to be a strong ally. The main reason for it is simple: its documentation is more than enough to get the work done. The only problem is that getting that very same job to look slightly ok is rather tedious.
To produce your PDF I would suggest a `pdfCreatorMethod()` similar to this:

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const fs = require("fs");

const doc = new PDFDocument({ autoFirstPage: false });

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('PATH/TO/YOUR/PDF'));

doc.registerFont("Helvetica", "client/assets/fonts/Helvetica-01.ttf");
doc.registerFont(
"HelveticaBold",
"client/assets/fonts/Helvetica-Bold-02.ttf"
);

doc.font("Helvetica").fontSize(10).fillColor("#80B3BD").text("", 70, 80, {
width: 100,
align: "left",
lineBreak: true,
});

/**
 * ADD WHATEVER YOU WANT TO YOUR FILE
 */

doc.end();
```

Allowing you to include any information that you desire in the document. After this, you will only need your route to serve the path to the file you created:

```
router.put("/mypdf", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      pdfCreatorMethod(req);
      res.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
      return res.status(201).sendFile('PATH/TO/YOUR/PDF');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return res.status(500).send({ error: e.message });
    }
});
```